# SQLNonTransientConnectionException when database is unreachable using JDBC template

Tags: java, spring

assuming the following:

```
  private static NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public static SqlRowSet foo(String value) {

    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("paramName", value);
    String query = "SELECT * from myTable WHERE paramName = :value";

    try {
      SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, params);
      return rs;
    } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException | DataAccessException e) {
      // do something 
    }
  }
```

This use the Spring library JdbcTemplate to interact with a Database. It works great when the connectivity to the database is up, but create a `SQLNonTransientConnectionException` exception if it is down (at line `SqlRowSet rs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, params);`)

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=63306)(type=master) : Connection refused
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:234)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:95)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1203)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:560)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:174)
            at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:92)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:611)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:693)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:307)
```

Instead of printing the stack trace, I would like to catch the exception. However, adding a `catch (SQLNonTransientConnectionException)` give me an error saying that this exception is never thrown. If I understand correctly, that mean there is a `printStackTrace` somewhere in the Spring library and the exception is never thrown up to my method, so I can't do anything to catch it except by modifying the Spring library?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about adding a generic Exception in catch block. It will catch every exception. After your catch block make another catch block `catch(Exception e)`

Comment: @Silverfang This does not work as no exception are thrown.

Comment: Spring wraps all exceptions in a `DataAccessException` so obviously trying to catch it won't work. Also this isn't logging from spring but rather from your connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the class `HikariPool.java` at line 390.

```
private void throwPoolInitializationException(Throwable t) {
    this.LOGGER.error("{} - Exception during pool initialization.", this.poolName, t);
    this.destroyHouseKeepingExecutorService();
    throw new HikariPool.PoolInitializationException(t);
  }
```

This log the stack trace and display it to the console. Disable log in `application.properties` for this class solve the problem.

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.pool=OFF
```